# Tikz: How to encapsulate shade in node?

Tags: latex, tikz

I have this shaded circle:

```
\shade [ball color=black!80!white] (0,0) circle (1);
```

Is it possible to encapsulate it with node style?
(Including fixing circle radius?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\node[shade,shading=ball,circle,ball color=black!80!white,minimum size=1cm] {};`

Comment: Great! I will put it in style.
Can I enforce maximum size?

Comment: @Łukasz, not using a built-in tikz parameter (afaik). Unless you put text inside the node, you shouldn't have anything to worry about, though. And even so, you could probably apply some general TeX-magic to restrict the size of the box.